# Jenkinsfile syntax: Commit to Subversion SCM repository from workspace

Tags: jenkins, svn, version-control, jenkins-pipeline, commit

Somehow, I could not find an example of declarative pipeline syntax (Jenkinsfile) for this case.

The idea is very simple. There is some local file in Jenkins pipeline workspace that was checked out from Subversion SCM repository at the beginning of a pipeline stage, it was checked out from under some branch.

I modified this file and at the end of a pipeline stage I need to commit this file back into SCM repository.

Does anybody have Jenkins pipeline DSL syntax example for such commit? This commit should be able to overwrite the file available under the branch in SCM repository.

Comment: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/push-git-repo/pushGitRepo.groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to "override" the commit but to add another commit that will update the file, right? Indeed it's a good practice to know where the changes on your repository come from.

For Subversion you should do something like

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId:'mycreds', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
  sh "svn commit --message 'jenkins update' --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username $USERNAME --password $PASSWORD"
}
```

Note: mycreds would be the id of a username/password credential you stored in jenkins

Finally making jenkins do commit is something you want to discuss with your team before implementing it, it can be hard to maintain if not done properly

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need to commit some configuration container file to a branch in Subversion. That branch would be used to keep such configuration containers. I would like to use existing Jenkins credentials IDs to do commits.

Comment: so it requires installation of the svn client into the jenkins host (image)
thats what i tried to avoid since the official images doesnt have it.

Comment: You should never have to modify the image jenkins is installed on. Instead, you should use a slave to run your builds on, or docker images, and ideally I would go with a Kubernetes cluster that allows me to run, the time of a build, 1 slave + other containers I might need for integration testing on demand. if no slave image on docker hub matches your needs or if you want to add some security to your image, I would recommend to give packer and its docker plugin a try